# displaytag slf4j dependency and spring tests errors

Tags: spring, maven, slf4j

i have problems with my spring tests and displaytag dependency in pom.

my pom dependencies are

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.entando.entando.bundles.misc</groupId>
        <artifactId>entando-misc-less</artifactId>
        <version>${entando.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.entando.entando.bundles.misc</groupId>
        <artifactId>entando-misc-bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>${entando.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.entando.entando.bundles.pages</groupId>
        <artifactId>entando-page-bootstrap-hero</artifactId>
        <version>${entando.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.entando.entando</groupId>
        <artifactId>entando-core-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${entando.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.entando.entando</groupId>
        <artifactId>entando-core-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${entando.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.entando.entando</groupId>
        <artifactId>entando-core-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${entando.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>10.8.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
        <version>10.8.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- STRUTS2 annotation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.16.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- STRUTS2 SPRING integration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.15.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.10</version>
    </dependency>       

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.17.1-GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.16.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
        <artifactId>displaytag</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>       

    <!-- import ed export -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
        <artifactId>flying-saucer-core</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
        <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.6</version>
    </dependency>                                        

</dependencies>
```

and i wrote some tests for dao, such as

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {        
        "classpath:META-INF/openMED-context-test.xml"
})
public class TestAddressBookJpaController {

    /**
     * Esegue il test sul load
     */
    @Test
    public void testLoadAll() {
        List<AddressBook> list = this.addressBookDAO.findAddressBookEntities();
        Assert.assertNotNull(list);
        Assert.assertEquals(22, list.size());
    }
```

when i run tests i get this error

```
org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.error(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:173)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:314)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

but if i remove the displaytag dependency from pom all work....
What's happening? I can't find the problem :-(

thanks

andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is due to the fact that you have multiple versions of the same class in your classpath. Typically this is caused by two dependencies which in turn each has a dependency to the same library, but with different versions.

In order to deal with this, run a `mvn dependency:tree` (`mvn dependency:tree > tree.txt` if your project is large). Then find all dependencies to the library in question (slf4j), and see what versions are there.

When you've found the version you want to keep (typically the highest), do:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>library.that</groupId>
    <artifactId>i.want</artifactId>
    <version>The.right.version</version>
```

(This will override any transitive dependencies for this library to be the version specified.)

Alternatively, you can exclude the library in the dependency which has a transitive to the version you *don't* want:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>library.with</groupId>
    <artifactId>bad.transitive.dependency</artifactId>
    <version>some.version</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion> 
            <groupId>library.that</groupId>
            <artifactId>i.want</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
```

This way, the transitive dependency for this library will be ignored.

Comment: in fact i have the dependency of the 1.7.5 version in 2 other artifacts.
I just tried your first solution adding the explicit dependency of that version in my pom.... but with no results

Comment: There are two dependencies in this error message, the class that tries to call, SLF4JLocationAwareLog, is found in jcl-over-slf4j.jar, while the class which lacks a method, LocationAwareLogger, is found in slf4j-api.jar. Make sure that you have only one version of both of these, and the versions are compatible.

Comment: ok ... solved... there was a nested nested dependency of jcl-over-slf4j version 1.6.6 ...i added also the exclusion of that artifact in displaytag and now it works.... thanks :-)